# Why did apt remove of ghostscript "ruined" my machine?

Tags: apt, 19.04

I removed ghostscript from my machine, but beside removing ghostscript it also ruined my GUI and messed up my network(machine had no internet). 
I was able to fix this, but I wonder what is the cause of this behavior. 
This is the update log:

> 1 Start-Date: 2019-11-28  14:11:57
>
> 2 Commandline: apt remove ghostscript
>
> 3 Requested-By: johnsmith (1000)
>
> 4 Install: libpaps0:amd64 (0.6.8-7.1, automatic), foomatic-filters:amd64 (4.0.17-11, automatic), paps:amd64 (0.6.8-7.1, automatic), libgpg-error-l10n:amd64 (1.35-1, automatic)
>
> 5 Upgrade: gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 (3.32.0-1ubuntu1, 3.32.1-0ubuntu1), language-selector-common:amd64 (0.194, 0.194.1), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:19.04.16, 1:19.04.16.    9), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:19.04.16, 1:19.04.16.9), libuuid1:amd64 (2.33.1-0.1ubuntu2, 2.33.1-0.1ubuntu3), libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1b-1ubuntu2, 1.1.1b-1ubuntu2.4), gno    me-software-common:amd64 (3.30.6-2ubuntu3, 3.30.6-2ubuntu4.19.04.2)
>
> 6 Remove: network-manager-pptp:amd64 (1.2.8-2), netplan.io:amd64 (0.96-0ubuntu4), gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64 (19.01.1-1), ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 (1.431), printe    r-driver-splix:amd64 (2.0.0+svn315-7fakesync1), gvfs-backends:amd64 (1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1), gnome-control-center:amd64 (1:3.32.1-1ubuntu4), friendly-recovery:amd64 (0.2.39), bluez-cu    ps:amd64 (5.50-0ubuntu2), printer-driver-hpcups:amd64 (3.19.1+dfsg0-1), gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 (3.30.6-2ubuntu3), libpam-fprintd:amd64 (0.8.1-1), ubuntu-system-service:a    md64 (0.4), fprintd:amd64 (0.8.1-1), rtkit:amd64 (0.12-4), snapd:amd64 (2.38+19.04), update-manager:amd64 (1:19.04.5), python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu21)    , gnome-software:amd64 (3.30.6-2ubuntu3), usb-creator-common:amd64 (0.3.5ubuntu19.04.1), ubuntu-standard:amd64 (1.431), ubuntu-session:amd64 (3.32.0-1ubuntu1), ubuntu-desktop:amd6    4 (1.431), gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 (3.32.0-1ubuntu1), plymouth-label:amd64 (0.9.4-1ubuntu1), printer-driver-pxljr:amd64 (1.4+repack0-5), usb-creator-gtk:amd64 (0.3.5ubuntu19.0    4.1), plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:amd64 (0.9.4-1ubuntu1), network-manager-gnome:amd64 (1.8.20-1ubuntu1), gdm3:amd64 (3.32.0-1ubuntu1), iio-sensor-proxy:amd64 (2.5-0ubuntu1), networ    k-manager:amd64 (1.16.0-0ubuntu2), packagekit-tools:amd64 (1.1.12-5), software-properties-gtk:amd64 (0.97.11), gnome-disk-utility:amd64 (3.32.1-1ubuntu1), apturl:amd64 (0.5.2ubunt    u17), ubuntu-minimal:amd64 (1.431), nautilus-share:amd64 (0.7.3-2ubuntu3), cups-filters:amd64 (1.22.5-1), udisks2:amd64 (2.8.2-1), gvfs-fuse:amd64 (1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1), nautilus:am    d64 (1:3.32.0-0ubuntu2), ubuntu-software:amd64 (3.30.6-2ubuntu3), printer-driver-sag-gdi:amd64 (0.1-7), network-manager-openvpn:amd64 (1.8.10-1), hplip:amd64 (3.19.1+dfsg0-1), pri    nter-driver-gutenprint:amd64 (5.3.1-7build1), brltty:amd64 (5.6-10ubuntu1), libpam-systemd:amd64 (240-6ubuntu5.7), ghostscript:amd64 (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu7.4), packagekit:amd64 (1.    1.12-5), gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 (28-1), ghostscript-x:amd64 (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu7.4), libnss-systemd:amd64 (240-6ubuntu5.7), gnome-initial-setup:amd64 (3.32.1-1u    buntu3), network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu:amd64 (1.16.0-0ubuntu2), plymouth:amd64 (0.9.4-1ubuntu1), printer-driver-pnm2ppa:amd64 (1.13+nondbs-0ubuntu6), policykit-1:amd6    4 (0.105-25), gvfs:amd64 (1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1), python3-aptdaemon:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu21), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:19.04.16), network-manager-openvpn-gnome:amd64     (1.8.10-1), gnome-shell:amd64 (3.32.0+git20190410-1ubuntu1), dbus-user-session:amd64 (1.12.12-1ubuntu1.1), aptdaemon:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu21), language-selector-gnome:amd64     (0.194), plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo:amd64 (0.9.4-1ubuntu1), printer-driver-ptouch:amd64 (1.4.2-3), cups:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1), gstreamer1.0-packagekit:amd64 (1.1.12-5), netwo    rk-manager-pptp-gnome:amd64 (1.2.8-2), update-notifier:amd64 (3.192.18), gvfs-daemons:amd64 (1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1), colord:amd64 (1.4.3-4), gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 (6    4ubuntu7)
>
> 7 End-Date: 2019-11-28  14:12:37

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you running? I wasn't able to replicate the behavior in 18.04 (LTS).

Comment: @Patch it is in the tag

Comment: To try to replicate this issue, I spun up a disco vm with multipass, and did "apt install ubuntu-desktop." I then tried removing ghostscript. Those steps don't cause the issue that you saw above. The network manager and other services don't depend on ghostscript. Did you have any other actions queued up?

Comment: @Patch checked my log, it is 10 lines long, so I cant give you more data.  Also note that I never did apt install ubuntu-desktop, I just made an VM from ISO image downloaded from ubuntu site, it was not a "server edition"(if they sill have those GUI free ISOs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Printing is considered an essential component of a desktop environment. In Linux, postscript is central in printing. Probably put way to simple, when applications print, they generate postscript. Postscript is understood directly by postscript printer. For non-postscript printers, ghostscript is relied upon by the printer drivers to translate the postscript to the appropriate printing language. Ghostscript is also used by document viewers such as Evince to display postscript files. Because ghostscript is core to the operating system, removing it removes a lot of components of the standard Ubuntu desktop that depend on it.

Removing `ghostscript` also will have removed the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage. You can conveniently restore your system by reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`. Doing so will pull all packages back in that are considered core of an Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 4):

Buried in that big, long list is the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage. That's important.

The usual scenario for this kind of mass-removal is as folows:

- You installed from the mino.iso or netinstall.iso
- Then you installed `ubuntu-desktop` (which requires `ghostscript`), You could have installed `ubuntu-desktop` directly or by using tasksel.
- You forgot (or did not understand) that your entire desktop stack was depending upon a single key package (`ubuntu-desktop`)
- Then you unintentionally removed that single key package, and watched the great collapse that it's removal caused.

The system includes an important safeguard to prevent unintended mass-removals: The confirmation dialog. I always recommend that folks read their apt output carefully before agreeing in order to prevent precisely this kind of surprise.

Additionally, the full-sized Ubuntu Desktop Installer includes another safeguard against mass-removal: It uses apt-mark to make all packages ineligible for autoremoval.

You can, obviously, restore your desktop stack by simply reinstalling the `ubuntu-desktop` package:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Removing ubuntu-desktop will *not* cause any mass-removal. Only packages that *depend* on a package will be removed if the package is removed, not the packages that *are a dependency* of the package. The latter may be "autoremoved" if they were automatically installed, otherwise not.

Comment: My installation was inside VM, I downloaded "normal" ISO from ubuntu website

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl then please provide the actual /var/log/apt/term.log for the relevant session. The edited version seems to have sanitized away key information.

Comment: @vanadium, completely agree. I think some element of the story is missing.